# Why Spring ReactiveMongoRepository does't have save method for Mono?

Tags: spring, mongodb, reactive-programming, spring-data-mongodb, project-reactor

I have a MovieRepository which extended ReactiveMongoRepository. I want to save a single POJO in a reactive way. But ReactiveMongoRepository doesn't provide save method for Mono or Publisher. I have to use `block()` method or use the `saveAll` method in the ReactiveMongoRepository.

```java
public Mono<ServerResponse> create(ServerRequest request) {

    Mono<Movie> movieMono = request.bodyToMono(Movie.class);
    return movieRepository.save(movieMono.block()) //
            .flatMap((movie) -> ServerResponse.ok().body(fromObject(movie)));
}
```

Is there a better way to solve this kind of problem? I don't think use block method is a good idea for reactive programming.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
 Mono<Movie> movieMonoSaved = movieMono.flatMap(movieRepository::save);
 return ServerResponse.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(movieMonoSaved, Movie.class);
```

Comment: A single `save` looks quite useful still. We've raised [DATACMNS-1385](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-1385) to discuss the possibility to add one.